# How to Load data from Hadoop to Kafka using JAVA Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to Load data from HDFS to Kafka using Java (Map Reduce). 
Is there any Java API available? or Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Your question is either "asking for an external library" or "too broad" - either way, it's not a good question for StackOverflow - please read the [help] for what to ask. That said, the way you phrased it is ok on a forum website (which SO isn't) and it has been asked already on Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stream-data-stored-in-HDFS-to-Kafka

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? Much more standard would be to stream the data to Kafka *before* it hits HDFS, using Kafka Connect to then load it to HDFS - and then it is available in Kafka for use elsewhere.